# Laravel 4 Mail not passing data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Emails works fine with dummy data:

```
    Mail::send('emails.contact', $messageData, function ($message) use ($messageData) {
        $message->from('joetannorella@gmail.com', 'Joe');
        $message->to('joetannorella@gmail.com','Joe T')->subject('Email Test');
    });
```

But when I try to pass data into the email, it won't send. I know a common problem is not passing through data with the **use ($data)**, but I am doing this and it's still not working.

This is my code that will not work:

```
    $messageData = array(
        'name' => 'test name',
        'email' => 'test email',
        'message' => 'test message'
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $messageData, function ($message) Use ($messageData) {
        $message->from($messageData['email'], $messageData['name']);
        $message->to('joetannorella@gmail.com','Joe T')->subject('Email Test');
    });
```

I'm pretty stuck for ideas now!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `$message` as your variable - [see L4 docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#basic-usage).

So change it to something like "msg" - i.e.:

```
   $messageData = array(
        'name' => 'test name',
        'email' => 'test email',
        'msg' => 'test message'
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array( 'email' => 'sample@sample.com', 'first_name' => 'Lar', 'from' => 'sample@sample.comt', 'from_name' => 'Vel' );

Mail::send( 'email.welcome', $data, function( $message ) use ($data)
{
    $message->to( $data['email'] )->from( $data['from'], $data['first_name'] )->subject( 'Welcome!' );
});
```