# Laravel Mail::send how to pass data to mail View

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

How can i pass data from my **Controller** to my customized mail **View** ?

Here's my **controller**'s send mail method :

```
$data = array($user->pidm, $user->password);
Mail::send('emails.auth.registration', $data , function($message){
$message->to(Input::get('Email'), 'itsFromMe')
        ->subject('thisIsMySucject');
```

Here's my emails.auth.registration **View**

```
<p>You can login into our system by using login code and password :</p>
<p><b>Your Login Code :</b></p> <!-- I want to put $data value here !-->
<p><b>Your Password :</b></p>   <!--I want to put $password value here !-->
<p><b>Click here to login :</b>&nbsp;www.mydomain.com/login</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Mail not passing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991860/laravel-4-mail-not-passing-data)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Send data like this.

```
$data = [
           'data' => $user->pidm,
           'password' => $user->password
];
```

You can access it directly as `$data` and `$password` in email blade

Answer (score 19):

```
$data = [
       'data' => $user->pidm,
       'password' => $user->password
];
```

second argument of send method passes array $data to view page

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.registration',["data1"=>$data] , function($message)
```

Now, in your view page use can use $data as

```
User name : {{ $data1["data"] }}
password : {{ $data1["password"] }}
```

Answer (score 4):

The callback argument can be used to further configure the mail. Checkout the following example:

```
Mail::send('emails.dept_manager_strategic-objectives', ['email' => $email], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('info@primapluse.com', 'BusinessPluse');
        $m->to($user, 'admin')->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

for those using the simpleMail this might help :

```
  $message = (new MailMessage)
   ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'))
   ->line(Lang::getFromJson('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
   ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
   ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
  $message->viewData['data'] = $data;
        return $message;
```

Comment: This might have unintended consequences, as it's not the purpose of the viewData property!