# how to get properties of $message variable in mail view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, post, properties

I need to get name or phone from contact form in email. 
I have an error:

> ErrorException in  line 3: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Mail\Message::$name

**my code looks:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use Mail;
use Session;
class mailController extends Controller
{
    public function postContact(Request $request) {


    $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
    $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
    $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
    $subject = 'Регистрация';

    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $name,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'phone' => $phone
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message)use ($data){

        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->cc('lesia@tridentsoftlab.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
        $message->to($data['email']);
    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Your email was sent!');

    return redirect('/');


   }
}
```

And my view `emails.contact`:

```
<div>
    {{ $message->name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to use `$data->name`

Comment: share your contact form also ?

Comment: @Rbaskam I did it as you wrote. but in this case error " Undefined variable: data "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166175/laravel-mailsend-how-to-pass-data-to-mail-view

Comment: @Rishi 
`<form class="nobottommargin" action="{{ route('mail.contact') }}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="template-contactform-name"
                                   value="" class="sm-form-control required"/>
                    </form>
`

Comment: @Rbaskam , yes . you are right, when use only $name or $phone in view - it is working. thanks

Comment: Excellent I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing data to the view you can reference the name of the array key.

Reference [Using data in email view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166175/laravel-mailsend-how-to-pass-data-to-mail-view)

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply ADD.

<?php dd($message) ?>


Or simply, <?php var_dump($message) ?>

This should work.
```

Or in view, it should be $message['name']

Comment: error:
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Mail\Message as array

Comment: why dont you simply try to use $name variable in the view. I am not pretty sure, but this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try use, for get subject for sample:

`{{$message->getSubject()}}`