# Why giving undefined variable in sending Email attachment in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I can't pass any variable to Email body from Controller. I have searched many solutions but no is matching with me.

I am using Mailable. But it is empty. I am not sure it is creating problem or not.

```
public function __construct(){}

public function build(){}
```

I have tested with dummy Email without passing variable. Email is sending successfully. So, I think there is no problem with configuration.

Function in controller:

```
public function mail()
{
    $info = Invoice::find(65)->first();
    // 65 is giving me value. I have checked with dd()
    $data = [
        'invoice' => $info->invoiceNumber
    ];

    Mail::send(['text'=>'invoice.test'], $data, function($message) use($data){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.test');
    $message->to('example@gmail.com','John Smith')->subject('Send Mail from Laravel');
    $message->from('from@gmail.com','The Sender');
    $message->attachData($pdf->output(), 'Invoice.pdf');
   });

   return 'Email was sent';
}
```

test.blade.php

```
<h1>It is working!! {{ $invoice }}</h1>
```

Data sending style is followed by:
[Laravel Mail::send how to pass data to mail View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166175/laravel-mailsend-how-to-pass-data-to-mail-view)

Comment: `use($data,$pdf)` your $pdf variable is undefined cause of you didn't used it.

Comment: Used. But same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the $data with the PDF view:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.test', $data);
```

But if you want to add an email body content different with the PDF content, try this:

```
Mail::send([], $data, function($message) use($data){
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.test', $data);
   $message->to('example@gmail.com','John Smith')->subject('Send Mail from Laravel');
   $message->from('from@gmail.com','The Sender');
   $message->setBody('sample mail content');
   $message->attachData($pdf->output(), 'Invoice.pdf');
});
```