# Can't pass data to mail in laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I don't know what the problem could possibly be, I'm trying to pass data to my email form

```
Mail::send('emails/register', $a,  function($message) use ($a)
{
$message->from('xxx@xxx.com' , 'xxxx');
$message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))->bcc('michael@xxx.com')->subject('Registration Mail');
});
```

I'm using use($a), the array is

```
$a = array('msg' => $activate);
```

And I grab the data with

```
{{ $a['msg'] }}
```

But I still get the error

```
Undefined variable: a
```

I have found many answers regarding this, including this one:

[Laravel 4 Mail not passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991860/laravel-4-mail-not-passing-data)

but I can't find what I do different. Can someone advice?

Comment: In addition to the correct answer below, note that you do not need the use($a) statement to pass that data to the view.  The only time you would need the use($a) statement is if you were using the $a variable within your inline function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
{{$msg}}
```

instead of

```
{{$a['msg']}}
```